# Как узнать Mac-адрес и IMEI устройства Android в Unity3d

Tags: android, unity3d, imei, mac-address

Как узнать Mac-адрес и IMEI устройства Android в Unity3d?

Нашел способ но я не уверен в нем

```
string IMEI = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
```

он выдает что то вроде "84863c1b9061c97a8556e7dc970a011d6a272a19"

второй способ

```
AndroidJavaObject TM = new AndroidJavaObject("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");
string IMEI = TM.Call<string>("getDeviceId");
```

выдает что то более похожее на imei.

Можно ли узнать Mac-адрес через WifiManager?

И могу я быть уверен что IMEI будет верным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На форумах Unity есть официальная [тема с описанием](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unique-identifier-details.353256/) текущего алгоритма получения уникального идентифкатора для Android.

Если коротко - у них есть алгоритм получения, который сначала пытается получить уникальный идентификатор устройства, но для этого ему требуется разрешение READ_PHONE_STATE, если его нет о пытается получить ANDROID_ID, если и это не получается - возвращает Mac-адрес. Существует проблема из-за которой, некоторые планшеты на Android не могут вернуть Mac-адрес, если не подключены к Wi-Fi, поэтому он и запрашивается в последнюю очередь.

Всё это происходит под коробкой, если вы вызываете [SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html). Однако, там же, в статье выше, есть и сам код на C#, который позволит вам получить с его помощью id самостоятельно любым из способов.